# Change database variable "character_set_client" in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I found out in my MySQL I have different global and database "character_set_client" variable. `show variables` shows

```
character_set_client | utf8
```

while `show global variables` shows

```
character_set_client | latin1
```

I believe the first one is database setting. How can I change it? When I do

```
set character_set_client='latin1'
```

it is changed only for session. When I disconnect and connect again it is set back to 'utf8'. How can I change it so that it stays at 'latin1'?

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to force the character set on the server side and tell it to skip negotiation regarding character set.
See [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-server.html)(V5.7 at time this was written).
Three parameters are vital for correct operation between client and server regarding that matter. They are set in the [mysqld] section of the .cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
#...    
#UTF8 stuff
skip-character-set-client-handshake
collation-server=latin1_general_ci
character-set-server=latin1
```

Side note, on this day and age one should always use UTF8, which would require setting the following lines:

```
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server=utf8mb4
```

Side-side note, since the release of MySQL 8.0 [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-server.html), the correct values would be:

```
collation-server=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
character-set-server=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Side-side note: MySQL's implementation of `utf8` is non-standard. What you _really_ should require is `utf8mb4` character set and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation.

Comment: The comment above is so important that might be worth editing the answer @photon0

Answer (score -2):

If you want to change the default for the database (and thus for all users of the database) and you are the administrator of the database, you can either compile it into the `mysqld` build:

```
configure --with-charset=latin1
```

or include it on the command line whenever your server starts/restarts:

```
mysqld --character-set-server=latin1
```

See [this reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-server.html).

If you don't want to change the defaults for the server but you do want to change *your* default when connecting, then you can use the client command line parameter `--default-character-set` as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_default-character-set).

They may also be a way to apply that setting in your `.my.cnf` file, but I don't know it offhand.